# Requests. Formulate key value dict for post request, real example

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a message with python requests library.

```
url: http://teamfinding.com/ru/message/login/toshak #  need auth, can be done via google or facebook
```

I found this pattern, nothing difficult:

```
payload = {'key': 'value', etc..}
session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://example.com/', data=payload)
```

**But I don't know, what key-values I should use?**

Copied HTML element

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/ru/message/login/toshak" method="post">  <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="PersonalMessage_FK_to_uid">Кому:</label>      <div class="controls">
            <input class="span6" value="toshak" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8" autocomplete="off" data-source="[]" placeholder="Введите логин пользователя" name="PersonalMessage[FK_to_uid]" id="PersonalMessage_FK_to_uid" type="text">          <span class="help-inline">
                        <a href="/ru/public/toshak"><img width="18" src="/cdn/users/529f8b174f227b87b7681b57050fe887/avatar/preview" class="avatar preview ">Антон Величко</a>                      </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="PersonalMessage_text">Текст сообщения:</label>        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="span6" rows="5" name="PersonalMessage[text]" id="PersonalMessage_text" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 110px;"></textarea>     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium" id="send-pm" name="yt0" data-one-click="true">
                Отправить сообщение <i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

screenshot of HTML form
[image: screenshot of HTML form]

Captured form via wireshark
[image: Captured form via wireshark]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the payload should be

```
{ "PersonalMessage_FK_to_uid": value_for_the_first_one, "PersonalMessage_text": value_for_the_second_one}

payload = { "PersonalMessage_FK_to_uid": value_for_the_first_one, "PersonalMessage_text": value_for_the_second_one}
session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://example.com/', data=payload)
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why exactly such keys? p.s. seems like you pasted payload twice

Comment: the keys are the id (html tag) 
<input id="PersonalMessage_FK_to_uid">